# ChromiumWebBrowser does not contain a definition for 'Reload'

Tags: .net, wpf, webbrowser-control, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using the CEF Sharp WPF web browser in my project. I was using the 37 version and now upgraded to the 65 version.  now I am getting the following error.

```
'ChromiumWebBrowser' does not contain a definition for 'Reload' and no extension method 'Reload' accepting a first argument of type 'ChromiumWebBrowser' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Could someone please let me know whether the API is removed or I need refer any other DLL?

Comment: @Downvoter: Please share the reason for improving the question instead of simply downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

`Reload()` is an extension method of the `IWebBrowser` interface which the `ChromiumWebBrowser` class implements.

It should compile (tested in version 65.0.1) if you add the following using directive in your code file:

```
using CefSharp;
```

**Code:**

```
CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser = new CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser();
//...
chromiumWebBrowser.Reload();
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. But from the documentation the API seems to be available in the WebBrowserExtensions class and not available in the ChromiumWebBrowser class.

http://cefsharp.github.io/api/57.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload.htm

Could you please share the API documentation link for accessing the reload method from the browser class.

Comment: As I stated in my answer it's an extension method, i.e. the method is not defined in the ChromiumWebBrowser itself. That's why you need the using directive for the compiler to find the method in the WebBrowserExtensions class.